# r - Filtering rows of a data.frame using a index

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, machine-learning, split

I have a data.frame, called `sonar`. The content of the first row is:

[image: first row of the data.frame]

Also, I have a vector of index; `index = c(1:N)`. I need to sample index and then split it in 5 parts. Then, I need to take 5 groups of rows, each group have the rows of the data.frame given by a part of the vector index.

I have done the following:

```
partitions = split(index, cut(seq_along(index), 5, labels = F))
```

So I have my parts in `partitions[1]`, `partitions[2]`... These are lists.

What I have to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the groups of rows in a list `df.groups` with

```
df.groups <- lapply(partitions, function(part) df[part,])
```

So the first group of rows is `df.groups[[1]]`, et cetera.